# How to display 0 as the first value in the y-axis with a axis y discontinuity

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have the following graph where I want to skip [0,50) since I won't have y values in this range. However, I want the value before the discontinuity to be 0 instead of 50. Then the first value above the discontinuity to be 50 instead of 60. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Test},
    xlabel={X-Val},
    ylabel={Y-Val},
    xmajorgrids,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    % xtick=data,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom,
    ymin=50, ymax=110,
    % ytick=data,
    ytick={0,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    ytickmin=50,
    % enlargelimits=false,
    legend pos=north west,
    xlabel style={yshift=-0.7cm},
        x tick label style={
            yshift=-0.2cm,
            xshift=0.2cm,
            rotate=45,
            anchor=east,
        },
    ymajorgrids,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,50)(2,60)(3,70)(4,80)(5,88)
    };
    \legend{Legend}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The following is how I want the y axis to be

[image]

When I have the minimum y axis value as 0, this happens

[image]

Comment: I delete my answer since it is not clear what you after. Edited answer was replicate y-axis as you show in added image to edited question, but as you claim, this is not what you like to have.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ close voters I think the question is quite clear, voting to leave open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With considering @Zarko's answer, I figured the solution.

I needed to add `extra y ticks` and `ymin` with a value lower than my minimum value by 10. And I needed an `extra y tick labels` with the value 0.

Since my minimum y value is 50, this is what I added,

```
extra y ticks={40},
extra y tick labels={0},
ymin=40,
```

This is the final code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Test},
    xlabel={X-Val},
    ylabel={Y-Val},
    xmajorgrids,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom,
    ymin=40, ymax=110,
    ytick={0,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    extra y ticks={40},
    extra y tick labels={0},
    legend pos=north west,
    xlabel style={yshift=-0.7cm},
        x tick label style={
            yshift=-0.2cm,
            xshift=0.2cm,
            rotate=45,
            anchor=east,
        },
    ymajorgrids,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,50)(2,60)(3,70)(4,80)(5,88)
    };
    \legend{Legend}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this an answer? This you should provide in question and not male plagiat, now deleted, of my answer. So, -1 for it!

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, but I honestly don't understand what is the problem with my question. I provided what I need in writing and demonstrated it in a picture. And I provided the code I have. You deleted your answer, which did not achieve the final thing I wanted, so I gave you credit in my answer that achieves what I need and explains it. I would love to understand so that I become better at this.